# qgis Error: Column type not supported using v.surf.idw

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have counts data from aerial measurements that I am trying to make an interpolation map from using Q.GIS 2.18.14. 
I have done a tutorial first with test data, then compared the test data to my data and don't see any obvious differences. The test data column type = double, same as my data. Yet when I run interpolation via the Interpolation plugin I just get nans, and when I try the v.surf.idw GRASS plugin I get the error: Column type not supported.

Can someone help me understand this?

(I have checked projections are correct).

Comment: Could you provide your data, or a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Sure, the shapefile and csv are on my github. https://github.com/tanyahelena/qgis_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the data sample to look at. It is hard for me to have confidence in my answer because I don't know anything about your data. When looking at it, it appears PDOP is the meaningful variable? Or maybe Altitude? The others are a timestamp, lat, long, and variables which do not change (Cobalt-60, Celsium-137, Eu-152). So I ran the IDW tool using PDOP as my variable. Here is what the data looks like for everyone else to see:
[image]

Anyway, I have not worked in QGIS 2.18 for a while, but it is possible your older version is the problem? You might want to consider upgrading to QGIS 3.4 (current long term release version).

Instead of using the GRASS r.surf.idw tool, QGIS provides a built-in 'IDW interpolation' tool, which I used with no problems. Sometimes GRASS tools can be weird to use if you are not used to them. If you are looking for a python solution, here is code running this tool using your data as an example:

```
import processing

layer_path = '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/qgis_data-master/area3_testdata_clipped.shp' 

parameters = {
    'DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT' : 2,
    'EXTENT' : '-116.04415744105579,-116.0047567429083,37.029018114312905,37.054281406967974 [EPSG:4326]',
    'INTERPOLATION_DATA' : '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/qgis_data-master/area3_testdata_clipped.shp::~::0::~::1::~::0',       #gets the vector layer and attribute information
    'PIXEL_SIZE' : 0.000241,                            #defines size of output raster cells
    'OUTPUT' : '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/OUTPUT.tif'}        #save the output where you want

processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:idwinterpolation', parameters)
```

A really nice trick to get the python code easily is to first run the IDW Interpolation tool via the widget/dialog box and then look at the 'log' tab. You are provided the python code in order to write your script. Here is what my log tab looks like after running the tool:
[image]

If you compare my log panel to my parameters dictionary in my code example, you'll see they are exactly the same. The only difference is the `OUTPUT`, I saved my layer as temporary, but gave you a path for the output in my example.

----------Update---------

Here is a code example for using the GRASS v.idw.surf tool.  Note: You need to upgrade to QGIS v3.6 in order for this code to produce a result.

```
import processing

parameters = {
'input' : '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/qgis_data-master/area3_testdata_clipped.shp',
'npoints' : 12,
'power' : 2,
'column' : 'PDOP',
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : '-116.04415744105579,-116.0047567429083,37.029018114312905,37.054281406967974 [EPSG:4326]',
'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0,
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '',
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '',
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1,
'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001,
'output' : '/Users/ep9k/Desktop/GRASS_OUTPUT.tif'}

processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.surf.idw', parameters)
```